# Dynamic validation

Tags: laravel, laravel-backpack

I am trying to put in dynamic validation rule inside my Request where the quantity requested should not be more than the AVAILABLE_QUANTITY (which gets updated for each despatch).

So my code in Request (FormRequest) is like this:

```
public function validator()
{

    $validator = Validator::make($this->request->all(), [
        'quantity' => [
            'required',
            'min:0',
            function ($attribute, $value, $fail) {
                
                $despatchentry =  $this->route('despatchentry');    
                
                if ($value > $despatchentry->materialentry->remainingquantity) {
                    $fail($attribute.' VERY BAD AND is invalid.');
                }
            },
         ],
    ]);
    
     return $validator;
}
```

However $this->route('despatchentry') returns null so I am not able to access the filled form values from there.

**I am using Laravel-Backpack.**

Comment: there is supposed to be route model binding going on for the action this current request is going to?

Comment: Sorry, I do not get your question fully.  However there is a Model behind this (DespatchEntry) which my controller is handling.  I have not added any further methods or binding logic.  May be that is the portion I am missing.

Comment: the route for the URL you are hitting has this route parameter named `despatchentry`? and there is route model binding whether implicit or explicit?

Comment: Yes, I have this on my backpack/custom.php (which is a custom route file used by backpack).

Route::crud('despatchentry', 'DespatchEntryCrudController');

Also, I am able to do basic validation like 'quantity' => 'required' on my Request without any issues.  I believe the my DespatchEntryController would bind my Model (DespatchEntry) to the Request.